# What can I use to track which button was pressed?

Tags: java, android, variables

I have a button that I touch to enter a game mode. All buttons start the same activity, but the rules and physics are changed depending on what you touch.

I want to track the button pressed so that I can know if people selected Classic mode or Training mode, and set the rules accordingly. How would I do this?

Here is how I start my game modes from the menu:

```
MenuElement classic = mElements.get(0);
    MenuElement training = mElements.get(1);

        if(touchX > classic.mX  && touchX < classic.mX + classic.mBitmap.getWidth() 
           && touchY > classic.mY   && touchY < classic.mY + classic.mBitmap.getHeight())
        {
            aux = "Starting game";
            Context context = com.Juggle2.Menu.this.getContext(); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartGame.class);
            intent.putExtra("rule", 1);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        if(touchX > training.mX  && touchX < training.mX + classic.mBitmap.getWidth() 
           && touchY > training.mY   && touchY < training.mY + training.mBitmap.getHeight())
        {
            aux = "Starting training";
            Context context = com.Juggle2.Menu.this.getContext(); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartGame.class);
            intent.putExtra("rule", 2);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And here is where it goes:

```
public class StartGame extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new Panel (this));      //Start the game

    }
}
```

Now I need that bundle of extras to be accessible by my Panel class, which is a SurfaceView.

---

Oh, I got it:

I found a way to do what I wanted  in a lot less steps

```
public class Global{
    public static int rules = 0;
}
```

And now I can just access those rules whenever and wherever I want by typing `Global.rules`

That seems so simple, in hindsight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted  in a lot less steps

```
public class Global{
    public static int rules = 0;
}
```

And now I can just access those rules whenever and wherever I want by typing `Global.rules`

Answer (score 2):

You can add an "extra" to your `Intent`s that start your activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartGame.class);
intent.putExtra(String key, X value);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can then get these extras in your StartGame Activity through:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
X value = extras.getX(String key);
```

where X is some type of data (e.g., String, int, long, double, etc.).

**Update**

Sorry, I didn't read your comment closely enough.  Here's a shot at something that might work for you:

```
public class StartGame extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Panel mPanel = new Panel(this, extras);

    setContentView(mPanel);      //Start the game
    }
}
```

And change your Panel constructor to accept a Bundle parameter, so you have those values on initialization.  Let me know how that works.

Comment: Thank you, but my Activity simply starts the SurfaceView, which is where I need those variables. How can I do pass those variables one class further?

Comment: Thank you again, but I'm not passing it one Activity further. The activity merely sets the content view to my SurfaceView.  I'll post my Activity to show you what I'm talking about. *Edit* Okay, I edited my question with more information. I want that bundle of extras to end up being accessible to my Panel class

Comment: Edited the edit. Edit: Alternatively, since you only have the one "rule" extra, you could pass that as the extra parameter.

Comment: That should work, but I found a far easier way to do what I wanted to do. I'll edit my own question to show what I did

Answer (score 0):

You should use a librairy where all this is done. Otherwise you will have to 
1) collect the stats
2) upload them to some place where you can look at the results, this part can be tricky to do by yourself

But google analytics does this all for you already. Maybe others too...
Here is the [starter page](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I don't want to track the button pressed for metrics purposes, I want to track the button pressed so that I can know if people selected `Classic` mode or `Training` mode, and set the rules accordingly